# how to check if gcloud backend service/url map are ready

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-sdk

Is there a way to determine if a backend service is ready? I ask because I run a script that creates a backend then a url map that uses this backend. The problem is I sometimes get errors saying the backend is not ready for use. I need to be able to pause until the backend is ready before I create a url map. I could check the error response for the phrase `'is not ready'` but this isn't reliable for future versions of gcloud. This is somewhat related to another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53257414/how-to-identify-gcloud-errors-in-scripts) I recently made on how to reliably check for gcloud errors.

I could also say the same for the url map. When i create a proxy that uses the url map, sometimes i get the error saying the url map is not ready.

Here's an example of what I'm experiencing:

```
gcloud compute url-maps add-path-matcher app-url-map 
    --path-matcher-name=web-path-matcher 
    --default-service=web-backend 
    --new-hosts="example.com" 
    --path-rules="/*=web-backend"

ERROR: (gcloud.compute.url-maps.add-path-matcher) Could not fetch resource:
 - The resource 'projects/my-project/global/backendServices/web-backend' is not ready



gcloud compute target-https-proxies create app-https-proxy 
    --url-map app-url-map 
    --ssl-certificates app-ssl-cert

ERROR: (gcloud.compute.target-https-proxies.create) Could not fetch resource:
 - The resource 'projects/my-project/global/urlMaps/app-url-map' is not ready



gcloud -v
Google Cloud SDK 225.0.0
beta 2018.11.09
bq 2.0.37
core 2018.11.09
gsutil 4.34
```

Answer (score 0):

would assume it's `gcloud alpha resources list` ...

see the [Error Messages](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/core_errors) of the Resource Manager and scroll down to the bottom, there it reads:

> **notReady** The API server is not ready to accept requests.

which equals `HTTP 503`, `SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE`.

adding the `--verbosity` option might provide some more details.

see the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/url-maps/add-path-matcher).

Comment: @Vincent you're missing one essential option on the command issued.

Comment: i think i can provide either the bucket or the service.

Comment: indeed. `exactly one of --default-service or --default-backend-bucket is required.` maybe try `gcloud compute url-maps list` to see if it even answers.

Comment: I tried `gcloud alpha resources list`,  but it doesn't look like it shows the state of the backend service/url map. For the backend service, it just shows @type/description/name fields.  The status code however is exactly what I'm trying to get. The `--log-http` option includes the json response w/ the status code, but how am i supposed to parse it out of all the other text? In the post i referenced, the `--log-http` output is shown.

Comment: I also tried a few times creating a dummy backend service and then immediately listing out all the backend services. Each time it would show up. I also tried creating them and then describing the specific backend right after. Each time it showed up but with no indicator that it wasnt ready.

Comment: `gcloud compute backend-services get-health web-backend` might provide some info. possibly one has to pass `--global` or a `--zone`. also under "Firewall Rules": https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/health-checks ...these source IPs need to be permitted to perform the health check. "not ready" at least means that there is a service by that name, opposite to "not found".

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue as well.

Then I have just checked with `$ gcloud components update`

Then received updates and the error is resolved.

you should try this.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).